# My Social Media icons are not linking to social media

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, menu, navbar, font-awesome

When I open hover over the icons the pointer finger doesn't show up. It doesn't link to any sites, and I'm not quite sure why. The icons are from font-awesome. I went into developers tools in 'inspect element' and it's still not clear as to why it's not working. The same links are working on the other pages. I added this code just before the opening body tag however I did try it within the navbar tag, and it didn't work. Thanks in advance for the help.

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse pull-right" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
       <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right social">
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Did you post this code **Before** body tag? Or you mean **After**?

Comment: @divy3993 although it is completely wrong to put it outside the `<body>` the code still should link. The issue will be somewhere else, although the body tag thing still will need to be fixed too :)

Comment: Ya I didn't mentioned that as an issue @AdamBuchananSmith

Comment: It's within the <body> I think I'm going to create a new folder and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Is the above code copied from your web page?

From looking at the code you posted, it's clear that these anchor tags  are not linking back to any website.

you simply need to alter the code slightly to link back to the social media page.

Inside each  tag there is href="#"
Where the # is, replace this with a link to the social media page.
So for example: if my twitter was "http://www.twitter.com/freelance_leeds" i would do the following:

```
<li><a href="http://www.twitter.com/freelance_leeds"><i class="fa fa-lg fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
```

This will need to be done for each link.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yeah sorry, I changed it just for this post, but it's not showing the hand when you hover over it.

Comment: Just to check my understanding - at the moment when you hover over it the 'hand' icon doesn't show. But if you click on it does it do anything? The hand icon could come down the the CSS styling on that web page

Comment: Thank you so much for offering to help. I put it through the W3C validator, and It showed an extra element in the code that I missed, that threw the entire code off.